# Search for NullPointerException in Log

Tags: bash, search, logging, nullpointerexception, tail

Can anyone guide/paste a command to search for all `NullPointerExceptions` in a log file.
As developers, we do watch logs for such issues and logs can be huge.

I am using `bash` and wants to find all `NullPointerExceptions` in log file, with above and below 10 lines, seperated by any specific design "------------------------------" like this.

Please, share it, much helpful, pretty newbie to *nix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `grep`,

```
grep -A10 -B10 'NullPointerExceptions' your.log
```